# Efficiently finding the first file (in the lexicographical sense) among multiple directories

Tags: find, sort

I have hundreds of folders and each folder contains thousands of files. I want to identify the "first" file among all files of all folders, "first" being defined by the lexicographical order of the filenames (excluding paths). For example:

```
/a/abc.txt
/b/aac.txt
/b/bxz.txt
```

Then the result should be `aac.txt`.

I am currently using this:

```
find . -iname "*" -printf "%f\n" | sort | head
```

But it is quite slow. Is there a better solution?

Comment: `locate` is much faster than `find`. Maybe you could use it.

Comment: Remove the `iname` and if by files you mean just regular files add `-type f`. Though a locate database as `Pyrophorus` mentioned, will still be faster.

Comment: Is all files has 3 letters in name itself ex: `aac.txt` and `abc.txt` and etc? since if you have a file with `aa.txt` name in a folder, your command still return `aac.txt` as first file while your first file is `aa.txt`!! and also [check here](http://superuser.com/questions/341232/faster-alternatives-to-find-and-locate) if you want command faster than `find` and also `locate`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can make it much faster as you need to first get the output of `find` which is the longest operation and only then pipe it through `sort` and `head`.

And if you're even considering putting some code together to make it run faster, I think the improvement (if any) over using `find` would be negligible when compared to the amount of time required to write it and make it more efficient than `find`.

Unless this is something you do regularly and the dataset is huge (thousands isn't that many), I wouldn't spend my time on it if I were you.